# Deduce length order of 4 decapeptides based on the Ramachandran plot

Tags: proteins

I have stumbled upon the following past exam question:

> 4 decapeptides A, B, C, D, made only of glycine residues, have
>   different conformations, and the phi and psi angles of individual
>   peptides are indicated on the Ramachandran plot (unfortunately I
>   cannot provide a specific plot). Order these peptides by decreasing
>   length.

How should I solve this, what information useful in solving this problem can I deduce from the Ramachandran plot?

Answer (score 1):

When φ = ψ = 180° the peptide is in the fully extended conformation i.e. it is the 'longest' it can be.

If it isn't possible to deduce a length order based on this information then I guess you will have to do some geometry to calculate the sums of the distances between the α C atoms using the known values for all of the bond angles - sounds laborious to me!

[This site](http://www.bmb.uga.edu/wampler/tutorial/prot2.html) tabulates values of φ/ψ for typical structures (helix, sheet, turn) so it may be possible to decide if some of peptides are adopting these.

Answer (score 1):

The Ramachandran plot describes secondary structure. If you see a lot of beta sheets in your plot you will have a more compact molecule than one which is wholly alpha helix. Gly can be almost anywhere in any quadrant. Look for residues with secondary structure to determine tertiary structure.